# apache rewrite with virtual host has recursion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite test.com to test.com/context.

The browser returns redirection recursion error.

Anyone has a clue?

I put below in httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com

    JkMount /* mschoi
    ErrorLog logs/mschoi-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mschoi-acces_log common

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /context/$1 [L,R]

</VirtualHost>

httpd.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple case of your rule matching `/context` again when it rewrites. You can just use a `RewriteCond` to avoid it:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite only if the request doesn't already match /context
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/context
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /context/$1 [L,R]
```

If the files being accessed actually exist (rather than a rewrite pattern) you can test for and not rewrite any real existing files:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the requested resource is not actually a real file or directory (doesn't exist)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /context/$1 [L,R]
```

#### Edit after comment to explain:

Not only per-directory rules can cause recursion. In this case, it is the simple matter that `/(.*)` matches *anything* and that gets appended unconditionally to `/content`. Since the `[R]` flag is present to redirect and each of these is a new request, it becomes a redirection chain of :

```
/something
/content/something
/content/content/something
/content/content/content/something
```

Subsequent redirects always continue to match the leading `/content` as well as what follows with `/(.*)` and append to it.

Comment: -1 - Does not explain why that has happened, since in my understanding only per-directory rewrite rules should be possible to cause recursion.

Comment: @Matmarbon It is actually pretty easy to illustrate. See my edit above if you need convincing.

Comment: Okay, sorry (restored -1). I did not notice the `[R]` as yet, my bad. I only really wondered because without the flag it would be very creepy ;)